# MSP430 program only works during debug mode

Tags: adc, c, msp430

I am trying to retrieve the values from the ADC on my MSP430F5529 and send them to my computer over USB, but I am starting small. All I have right now I something that retrieves the ADC value and stores it in ADCResults, if the read value is over half of Vcc then an LED turns on.

I have pin 6.0 hooked up to a force sensor so I can see it turn off and on when I put my finger down on it or release it.

The program works perfectly when I run it in debug mode but when I try to run it outside debug mode (just powering the board from the computer after the code is downloaded to it), nothing happens when I put my finger on the force sensor.

Whats extremely odd is if i hold down reset while putting my finger on the force sensor (putting my finger down causes the LED to turn on), and release the reset button the LED stays on until I hit reset again with my finger off it, so it seems reset is causing an issue but I'm not sure how.

At first I thought reset was being pulled constantly high (or low, whatever resets the device), but that can't be true because then the program should work if I held reset down, but it doesn't!

Here is my code:

```
#include "driverlib.h"

volatile uint16_t ADCResults = 0;

void main(void)
{
    //Stop Watchdog Timer
    WDT_A_hold(WDT_A_BASE);

    //P6.0 ADC option select
    GPIO_setAsPeripheralModuleFunctionOutputPin(
        GPIO_PORT_P6,
        GPIO_PIN0
        );

    GPIO_setAsOutputPin(
        GPIO_PORT_P1,
        GPIO_PIN0
        );

    //Initialize the ADC12_A_A Module
    /*
     * Base address of ADC12_A_A Module
     * Use internal ADC12_A_A bit as sample/hold signal to start conversion
     * USE MODOSC 5MHZ Digital Oscillator as clock source
     * Use default clock divider of 1
     */
    ADC12_A_init(ADC12_A_BASE,
                 ADC12_A_SAMPLEHOLDSOURCE_SC,
                 ADC12_A_CLOCKSOURCE_ADC12OSC,
                 ADC12_A_CLOCKDIVIDER_1);

    ADC12_A_enable(ADC12_A_BASE);

    /*
     * Base address of ADC12_A_A Module
     * For memory buffers 0-7 sample/hold for 64 clock cycles
     * For memory buffers 8-15 sample/hold for 4 clock cycles (default)
     * Disable Multiple Sampling
     */
    ADC12_A_setupSamplingTimer(ADC12_A_BASE,
                               ADC12_A_CYCLEHOLD_64_CYCLES,
                               ADC12_A_CYCLEHOLD_4_CYCLES,
                               ADC12_A_MULTIPLESAMPLESDISABLE);

    //Configure Memory Buffer
    /*
     * Base address of the ADC12_A_A Module
     * Configure memory buffer 0
     * Map input A0 to memory buffer 0
     * Vref+ = AVcc
     * Vr- = AVss
     * Memory buffer 0 is not the end of a sequence
     */
    ADC12_A_configureMemoryParam param = {0};
    param.memoryBufferControlIndex = ADC12_A_MEMORY_0;
    param.inputSourceSelect = ADC12_A_INPUT_A0;
    param.positiveRefVoltageSourceSelect = ADC12_A_VREFPOS_AVCC;
    param.negativeRefVoltageSourceSelect = ADC12_A_VREFNEG_AVSS;
    param.endOfSequence = ADC12_A_NOTENDOFSEQUENCE;
    ADC12_A_configureMemory(ADC12_A_BASE,&param);

    //Enable memory buffer 0 interrupt
    ADC12_A_clearInterrupt(ADC12_A_BASE,
                           ADC12IFG0);
    ADC12_A_enableInterrupt(ADC12_A_BASE,
                            ADC12IE0);

    while(1)
    {
        //Enable/Start sampling and conversion
        /*
         * Base address of ADC12_A_A Module
         * Start the conversion into memory buffer 0
         * Use the single-channel, single-conversion mode
         */
        ADC12_A_startConversion(ADC12_A_BASE,
                                ADC12_A_MEMORY_0,
                                ADC12_A_SINGLECHANNEL);

        //LPM0, ADC12_A_ISR will force exit
        __bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits + GIE);
        //for Debugger
        __no_operation();
    }
}

#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector=ADC12_VECTOR
__interrupt
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
__attribute__((interrupt(ADC12_VECTOR)))
#endif
void ADC12_A_ISR(void)
{
    switch(__even_in_range(ADC12IV,34))
    {
    case  0: break;       //Vector  0:  No interrupt
    case  2: break;       //Vector  2:  ADC overflow
    case  4: break;       //Vector  4:  ADC timing overflow
    case  6:              //Vector  6:  ADC12IFG0
        //Is Memory Buffer 0 = A0 > 0.5AVcc?

          ADCResults = ADC12_A_getResults(ADC12_A_BASE,
                                        ADC12_A_MEMORY_0);
        if(ADCResults
           >= 0x7ff)
        {
            //set P1.0
            GPIO_setOutputHighOnPin(
                GPIO_PORT_P1,
                GPIO_PIN0
                );
        }
        else
        {
            //Clear P1.0 LED off
            GPIO_setOutputLowOnPin(
                GPIO_PORT_P1,
                GPIO_PIN0
                );
        }

        //Exit active CPU
        __bic_SR_register_on_exit(LPM0_bits);
    case  8: break;       //Vector  8:  ADC12IFG1
    case 10: break;       //Vector 10:  ADC12IFG2
    case 12: break;       //Vector 12:  ADC12IFG3
    case 14: break;       //Vector 14:  ADC12IFG4
    case 16: break;       //Vector 16:  ADC12IFG5
    case 18: break;       //Vector 18:  ADC12IFG6
    case 20: break;       //Vector 20:  ADC12IFG7
    case 22: break;       //Vector 22:  ADC12IFG8
    case 24: break;       //Vector 24:  ADC12IFG9
    case 26: break;       //Vector 26:  ADC12IFG10
    case 28: break;       //Vector 28:  ADC12IFG11
    case 30: break;       //Vector 30:  ADC12IFG12
    case 32: break;       //Vector 32:  ADC12IFG13
    case 34: break;       //Vector 34:  ADC12IFG14
    default: break;
    }
}
```

***UPDATE***

I have tried do make the same functionality not using the peripheral driver library and it seems to work perfectly outside the debugger. This leads me to believe something is wrong with Texas Instruments Peripheral Driver Library.

Here is the code that seemed to work fine outside the debugger and doens't use the Peripheral Driver Library.

```
#include <msp430.h>

int main(void)
{
  WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;                 // Stop WDT
  ADC12CTL0 = ADC12SHT02 + ADC12ON;         // Sampling time, ADC12 on
  ADC12CTL1 = ADC12SHP;                     // Use sampling timer
  ADC12IE = 0x01;                           // Enable interrupt
  ADC12CTL0 |= ADC12ENC;
  P6SEL |= 0x01;                            // P6.0 ADC option select
  P1DIR |= 0x01;                            // P1.0 output

  while (1)
  {
    ADC12CTL0 |= ADC12SC;                   // Start sampling/conversion

    __bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits + GIE);     // LPM0, ADC12_ISR will force exit
    __no_operation();                       // For debugger
  }
}

#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector = ADC12_VECTOR
__interrupt void ADC12_ISR(void)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
void __attribute__ ((interrupt(ADC12_VECTOR))) ADC12_ISR (void)
#else
#error Compiler not supported!
#endif
{
  switch(__even_in_range(ADC12IV,34))
  {
  case  0: break;                           // Vector  0:  No interrupt
  case  2: break;                           // Vector  2:  ADC overflow
  case  4: break;                           // Vector  4:  ADC timing overflow
  case  6:                                  // Vector  6:  ADC12IFG0
    if (ADC12MEM0 >= 0x7ff)                 // ADC12MEM = A0 > 0.5AVcc?
      P1OUT |= BIT0;                        // P1.0 = 1
    else
      P1OUT &= ~BIT0;                       // P1.0 = 0

    __bic_SR_register_on_exit(LPM0_bits);   // Exit active CPU
  case  8: break;                           // Vector  8:  ADC12IFG1
  case 10: break;                           // Vector 10:  ADC12IFG2
  case 12: break;                           // Vector 12:  ADC12IFG3
  case 14: break;                           // Vector 14:  ADC12IFG4
  case 16: break;                           // Vector 16:  ADC12IFG5
  case 18: break;                           // Vector 18:  ADC12IFG6
  case 20: break;                           // Vector 20:  ADC12IFG7
  case 22: break;                           // Vector 22:  ADC12IFG8
  case 24: break;                           // Vector 24:  ADC12IFG9
  case 26: break;                           // Vector 26:  ADC12IFG10
  case 28: break;                           // Vector 28:  ADC12IFG11
  case 30: break;                           // Vector 30:  ADC12IFG12
  case 32: break;                           // Vector 32:  ADC12IFG13
  case 34: break;                           // Vector 34:  ADC12IFG14
  default: break; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you doing this on a LaunchPad or some other TI dev board? Or is this something you've designed?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with MSP430s to be sure, but: Could it be the WDT is force-enabled by a configure bit? Some uC allow you to force the WDT, which may be overridden by the DBGU module. Same goes for any other (protective) interrupt, if I were more familiar I would check your code, but interrupts are a very common source for this kind of behaviour. (Just like the division overflow interrupt: Doesn't get triggered in debug mode on many devices, but does get force-triggered when not in debug mode).

Comment: @DigitalNinja Yes i am on a Launchpad the MSP430F5529 Launchpad

Comment: @Asmyldof I am not sure if the WDT is doing it, the code clearly disables the WDT but i am still a novice so i have no idea.

Comment: @Aaron Best wait for someone with more experience, but most of the MCUs I have worked with allow a special bit to be set by the programming device that locks the WDT to on, such that the software turning it off has no effect. But it may well be something completely else, just thought I'd put my 2ct in until a guru inevitably zips by.

Comment: @Aaron The way you have described the operation with the reset button makes it sound like it's just simply being held in reset. You bring it out of reset, it see's your input then it goes back to being in reset when you remove the button press. Pressing it down again brings it out and re-initalizes the LED. Normally the debugger takes care of reset for you because it uses the reset line for programming. Have you double checked your jumper configuration? There is a jumper for reset labeled (RST).

Comment: @Aaron Additionally, I also have a LaunchPad that I've used just once, but didn't have an issue running the program outside of the debugger. I was using a different MSP430 with this line `WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD; // Stop watchdog timer` to stop the watchdog.

Comment: @Aaron, Usually you want to let the ADC settle before making the measurement. I have not don't anything with ADC on MSP430. But little work I have done on a ARM Cortex-M4, I let the ADC settle before I captured the measurement. But I don't claim to be an expert.I suggest changing 7ff to a lower value just for debugging.

Comment: The MSP430 doesn't work that way @Asmyldof

Comment: @DigitalNinja OP's on the F5529 launchpad, and using the msp430 driver library. The WDT_A_hold is a function to do the same as directly modifying the WDTCTL

Comment: OP this link [analog to digital converter](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/video/watch.tsp?entryid=0_7wz2r5v0) could help you.

Comment: i dont think the reset is being held because other programs work fine outside the debugger, like a simple button controlling LED program (push button makes led light up) works fine outside the debugger

Comment: For the `ADC12_A_clearInterrupt()` and `ADC12_A_enableInterrupt()`, you are not using the symbols that the documentation says you should use, but this does not actually matter.

Comment: Can you put a delay and an unconditional blinking of the other LED into the main loop, to see whether it runs at all?

Comment: yah let me try that right now and see if it gets into main, ill report back soon

Comment: @CL. it's getting into main, let me see if it stalls somewhere

Comment: @CL. It's getting everywhere in main, from the first line after WDTHold to inside the while loop, to even after the __no_operation() in the while loop, it seems to reach every point in main outside debug mode.

Comment: @CL. I just tested whether it gets into the ISR by making the green LED (the one i dont use in this program, turn on directly after `ADC12_A_getResults` is called. I turn it on no matter what (meaning its not a part of the if statement), and it turns on fine. So i know its at least triggering the ISR

Comment: @CL. So it looks like the only point in the program it doesn't seem to get into when not debugging is the if statement, but it gets there when i debug. Unless the problem is with taking many samples when not in debug mode (meaning it only gets into the if statement once), if it only got into the if statement once it would explain this odd reset behavior where it works depending on the state directly when reset is lifted.

Comment: @Aaron I'm not sure what this line `__bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits + GIE);` is doing. However, don't you need to clear the interrupt before starting another conversion? As in, call `ADC12_A_clearInterrupt(ADC12_A_BASE,ADC12IFG0);` after the conversion has completed. Maybe that's why it only reads the ADC once directly after reset.

Comment: @DigitalNinja I dont know what `__bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits + GIE)` is exactly doing either as it was already in the example code, but i believe it sets the MCU to low power mode and enables interrupts to take it out of low power mode. Interestingly enough, the code is getting into the ISR outside of debug mode, i testing this by making an LED toggle each time it enters the ISR and putting some delay cycles so i can actually see it flash. This makes the entire program work correctly!

Comment: @DigitalNinja So it seems that creating a delay lets the program work fine outside the compiler, what does this tell us about why it wont work normally? Why do i require a delay? all __delay_cycles does is a bunch of NOPs correct? Well what is happening during those NOPs that cause the program to work correctly?

Comment: @DigitalNinja I have made somewhat of a breakthrough, i have discovered that if you include `+ GIE` in the argument of the call `__bic_SR_register_on_exit` which is called right before the ISR exits the entire program works fine! I just don't know what these functions are doing

Comment: @Aaron Nice job. I'm assuming `GIE` is global interrupts enable. So it seems like without the `+ GIE` on that line (`__bic_SR_register_on_exit`), interrupts get disabled. Adding it enables interrupts and therefore you get the next ADC interrupt when re-entering the main loop.

Comment: @DigitalNinja Please correct me if i'm wrong but i am still confused because even without `+ GIE` the program worked so long as i put a delay inside the ISR

Comment: @Aaron Yeah, I was just thinking that even though the `+ GIE` isn't in that line in the ISR it would get called in the main loop (`__bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits + GIE)`) and re-enabling global interrupts if they had been disabled. So, it's really just the delay that fixed it, as you just pointed out. Where did you put the delay in the ISR and how long is the delay?

Comment: @Aaron Another thought is, do you care about the low power mode? If not, I'd say just remove those two lines that set the low power bits, and the problem might go away.

Comment: @DigitalNinja I dont know what you mean by main re-enabling the global interrupt, even if main called the `__bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits + GIE)` line after the ISR returned and thus set the GIE, why would the delay cause main to re-enable it but not having a delay cause main to not re-enable it. The delay was located directly before the `if(ADCResults >= 0x7ff)` statement inside the ISR

Comment: @DigitalNinja I do care about the low-power mode, not because i need it for this application specifically, but rather because i am a novice and want the experience of working with low-power mode. It is, after all, proper programming practice for embedded design

Comment: Clearing the GIE bit would *disable* any further interrupts. And the ADC interrupt already gets cleared by reading the `ADC12IV` register.

Comment: @CL. I dont think i fully understand what you are saying, why does the delay inside the ISR allow the main loop to re-assert the GIE bit?

Comment: @Aaron This comment thread is getting really long... I just meant that this line `__bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits + GIE)` enables global interrupts in your main loop, regardless of the delay or the other line in the ISR. I don't know why a delay there fixes it. I don't think you should need it. So something else is going on, maybe with the ADC configuration. Have you checked the TI forums for help or changed your code to exactly match an example?

Comment: Did you make *any* changes from TI's example program?

Comment: @Aaron Try changing this parameter `ADC12_A_CYCLEHOLD_64_CYCLES` in `ADC12_A_setupSamplingTimer` to also be `ADC12_A_CYCLEHOLD_4_CYCLES` and take out your delay code.

Comment: @DigitalNinja I agree this comment is huge, but i just want to know why this strange behavior is happening. I cant figure out why the delay is fixing the issue.

Comment: @CL. yes, i some libaries included that the example doesnt have, but i never reference them ever. I want to make it explicitly clear that these libraries are not the case becuase i JUST double checked by loading the example project (Without anything added whatsoever), and the exact same symptoms happen until i add either the delay or the `+ GIE` to the ISRs call of `__bic_SR_register_on_exit`. So i know the extra libaries are not causing the issue, i just cant figure out why the delay has the same effect as adding `+GIE`

Comment: @DigitalNinja changing that parameter causes the LED to not light up even INSIDE the debugger, let alone outside of it. I don't exactly know what this parameter does, but it's not helping because now the program doesnt even work in debug mode.

Comment: You should ask on [TI's forum](http://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/).

Comment: @Aaron it was just a wild guess. Fact of the matter is, you should not need a delay there. If you get this solved with TI's help please come back and post the answer.

Comment: @DigitalNinja if i figure it out i will definitely post the answer. Thanks for the support, with you're guys' help i've at least narrowed down the symptoms and possible solutions

Comment: `__bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits + GIE)` sets the Low Power Mode 0 and Global Interrupt Enable bits into the Special Register that controls the Sleep mode and Global Interrupts. The delay after setting the interrupt and sleep is to prevent issues with it getting stuck in sleep.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the reason for such behavior is that optimization settings are different in debug mode, and some variable that the compiler thinks isn't needed is then optimized right out.

The fixes for this are to add "volatile" qualifiers to such variables, or to turn optimization off (or at least turn it down).

I don't know if this is your answer (the thread becaume TL;DR), but this tidbit should certainly appear as a possible solution for the search engines.

Comment: `volatile` qualifier was there in the first code, so even though often an issue, in this case rather not

Comment: @Arsenal -- that's the variable he can  *see*.  Maybe there's something buried in a library he doesn't know about.  First pass for me would be to turn optimization off.  It takes ten minutes of reading to figure out how, you do it, and then you know.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Thanks for the suggestion, optimizations were off from the beginning, i pretty much always work with them off to start out with

Comment: The library casts every access to the hardware to a volatile pointer which then gets dereferenced, I have not seen them use any notable variable which could be optimized away.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I am not an expert on MSP430.

I suggest the use of

```
ADC12_A_disableConversions()
```

after

```
ADC12_A_setupSamplingTimer()
```

Excerpt from `MSP430 DriverLib for MSP430F5xx_6xx Devices`

---

#### void ADC12_A_startConversion (uint16_t baseAddress, uint16_t tartingMemoryBufferIndex, uint8_t conversionSequenceModeSelect)

> This function enables/starts the conversion process of the ADC. If the sample/hold signal source chosen during initialization was ADC12OSC, then the conversion is started immediately, otherwise the chosen sample/hold signal source starts the conversion by a rising edge of the signal. Keep in mind when selecting conversion modes, that for sequenced and/or repeated modes, to keep the sample/hold-and-convert process continuing without a trigger from the sample/hold signal source, the multiple samples must be enabled using the **ADC12_A_setupSamplingTimer()** function. Note that after this function is called, the **ADC12_A_disableConversions()** has to be called to re-initialize the ADC, reconfigure a memory buffer control, enable/disable the sampling timer, or to change the internal reference voltage.

Note: Also there are a few good free online course to learn embedded systems design. One of them uses MSP430. I have list few of them below.

---

**References:**

- [ADC12_A_startConversion driver library reference.](http://dev.ti.com/tirex/content/MSPware/MSPWare_2_21_00_39/driverlib/doc/MSP430F5xx_6xx/html/group__adc12__a__api.html#gad27e6fb2af444e5ec5a6268e5e66625a)
- [Embedded Systems - Shape The World from University of Texas at Austin](https://www.edx.org/course/embedded-systems-shape-world-utaustinx-ut-6-02x)
- [Electronic Interfaces: Bridging the Physical and Digital Worlds from University of California Berkeley](https://www.edx.org/course/electronic-interfaces-bridging-physical-uc-berkeleyx-ee40lx-0)
- [Getting Started with the MSP430 LaunchPad Workshop](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Getting_Started_with_the_MSP430_LaunchPad_Workshop?DCMP=MSP430&HQS=Other%20OT%20launchpad-workshop)
- [Getting Started with the MSP430 LaunchPad 9 Part Series](https://training.ti.com/getting-started-msp430-launchpad-9-part-series)

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why it works in debug mode, it's been a while since I worked with MSP430 and I'm not familiar with the driverlib. But:

```
GPIO_setAsPeripheralModuleFunctionOutputPin(
        GPIO_PORT_P6,
        GPIO_PIN0
        );
```

Surely isn't the function you want to use to switch this pin to an analog input or is it? I'd try:

```
GPIO_setAsPeripheralModuleFunctionIntputPin(
        GPIO_PORT_P6,
        GPIO_PIN0
        );
```

But as seen in the description of the [pin functions](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430f5529.pdf#page=93) (thanks @CL.) it becomes clear that setting the pin to the peripheral function will indeed be enough and the direction is ignored. So it's just misleading but not a deal breaker.

Then there is a small thing `param.endOfSequence = ADC12_A_NOTENDOFSEQUENCE;` which should probably be `param.endOfSequence = ADC12_A_ENDOFSEQUENCE;` but as you only do a single channel conversion, it shouldn't matter (it's just a bit more clear). And probably change `ADC12IFG0` and `ADC12IE0` to `ADC12_A_IFG0` and `ADC12_A_IE0` (but they are just defines to the other values, so no functional issue)

And you are missing a `break;` after your case in the interrupt vector table, but that won't affect the program much either, just a source for future bugs.

So from a firmware perspective I only have minor nitpicks.

Based on the comments, and reading through the [errata sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/er/slaz314p/slaz314p.pdf), makes me wonder if a single `__no_operation();` after the `__bic_SR_register_on_exit(LPM0_bits);` in the ISR would solve the problem. The errata doesn't explicitly mention the case present here, but there are problems involving setting low power modes, exiting low power modes and corrupting the program counter. So maybe it's another case. Those effects might not be present during debug as the emulation module interferes with normal execution of the core.

But you also mentioned, that if you clear the global interrupt enable your program works also. Which leads me to thinking that your program gets stuck in an interrupt but not the ADC one. You don't have to clear the interrupt flag of the ADC as that is automatically done when reading the memory of the ADC.

Just another note on programming, I'd get the analysis of the ADC value out of the ISR. Keep them as small as possible, just read the value into your global variable and leave the low power mode on exit. Do all the other stuff in your main application. There are cases where you will need a short as possible interrupt latency and if you do stuff inside the ISR you will block other interrupts (except you enable nested interrupts, but those are evil as well).

Comment: As the table on the next page shows, configuring the pin for module function (P6SEL.0 = 1) is enough; the direction does not matter.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, @Arsenal i think i have narrowed down the symptom, but not sure whats the cause. It seems it's only reading the ADC once directly after reset

Comment: @Arsenal i now know the problem has to do with delays and intrinsic functions, but i do not know enough about intrinsic functions to fix it

Comment: @Aaron I have changed my answer, maybe it helps a bit, for fun I added some general guidelines for ISRs as well.

Comment: @Arsenal thank you, i have looked into it. I am still trying new things and  thing ihave a breakthrough if you want to see my updated OP

Comment: @Aaron thanks for the update - I'll look into it, on a first view it seems like I'll have to dive into the TI library and see what they are doing.

Comment: @Aaron I've looked at the code of the peripheral library and I can't find something which is obviously wrong. Some things they do are not needed for a new start in conversion, but it shouldn't stop it from working. Maybe I'm too tired now. The one thing really standing out is that you don't touch the MCTL register, which the driver library does.

Comment: @Aaron I sort of give up, this problem drives me nuts. I started a bounty, maybe someone will come along and solve it. If you have news, please update the post, if you have a solution, post it as answer.